# How to create an accurate buffer of 5 miles around a coordinate in python?

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I  would like to create an accurate buffer of 5 miles around a coordinate, my current code is:

```
cpr_gdf['p_buffer']=cpr_gdf['coordinates'].buffer(5*(1/60))
```

The coordinates column was created with this code:

```
cpr_df['coordinates']=list(zip(cpr_df.sample_longitude_decimal,cpr_df.sample_latitude_decimal))
cpr_df['coordinates']=cpr_df['coordinates'].apply(Point)
cpr_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(cpr_df,geometry='coordinates',crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question? What about the code example you show does not work (as intended)?

Comment: One remark based on the code: your data is in longitude/latitude. If you want an accurate buffer in miles (meters), you will probably need to convert your data to another coordinate reference system that works in meters.

Comment: Hi, the code has been adjusted so it works :) should I post it in here or just delete the question.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert to an equal area projection that is most accurate to where your buffer will be (good resource at https://epsg.io/)

For example, I'm making maps in Michigan, so I'm using EPSG:3174 (which I believe is in meters, correct me if wrong). Given you've already converted your dataframe to a GeoPandas dataframe, you can convert your current projection to 3174 and then create your buffer (converting miles to meters)

```
cpr_gdf= cpr_gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3174'})  
buffer_length_in_meters = (5 * 1000) * 1.60934
cpr_gdf['geometry'] = cpr_gdf.geometry.buffer(buffer_length_in_meters)
```

Answer (score -1):

At the equator, one minute of latitude or longitude is ~ 1.84 km or 1.15 mi ([ref](http://www.longitudestore.com/how-big-is-one-gps-degree.html)).

So if you define your point as `P = [y, x]` then you can create a buffer around it of lets say 4 minutes which are approximately 5 miles: `buffer = 0.04`. The bounding box then is easily obtained with

```
minlat = P[0]-(P[0]*buffer)
maxlat = P[0]+(P[0]*buffer)
minlon = P[1]-(P[1]*buffer)
maxlon = P[1]+(P[1]*buffer)
```

Comment: this only works for certain latitudes, and is an approximation, at best. Results will be wildly skewed at the poles.

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate buffer over points without converting to any other CRS using the function bellow. But it calculates in meters, so if you want to use miles just multiply `distance` on 1609.34
Here is an example

```py
    from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
    import numpy as np
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon
    import pandas as pd
    import geopandas as gpd
    
    
    def geod_buffer(gdf, distance, resolution=16, geod = Geodesic.WGS84):
        """
        gdf - GeoDataFrame with geometry column
        distance - The radius of the buffer in meters
        resolution – The resolution of the buffer around each vertex
        geod - Define an ellipsoid
        """
        buffer = list()
        for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
            lon1, lat1 = row['geometry'].x, row['geometry'].y
            buffer_ = list()
            for azi1 in np.arange(0, 360, 90/resolution):
                properties = geod.Direct(lat1, lon1, azi1, distance)
                buffer_.append([properties['lon2'], properties['lat2']])
            buffer.append(Polygon(buffer_))
        return buffer
    
    
    locations = pd.DataFrame([
        {
         'longitude': 54.604972,
         'latitude': 18.346815},
        {
         'longitude': 54.605917,
         'latitude': 18.347249}
    ])
    
    locations_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(locations,
                                     geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(locations.longitude, locations.latitude),
                                     crs='epsg:4326').drop(columns=['longitude', 'latitude'])
    
    
    locations_gpd['geometry'] = geod_buffer(locations_gpd, 1000)
```