# setting right projection crs to geodataframe to calculate in meters

Tags: geopandas, proj

Even though there is an answer to my question [How to create an accurate buffer of 5 miles around a coordinate in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263138/how-to-create-an-accurate-buffer-of-5-miles-around-a-coordinate-in-python/53328861#53328861), but I can not represent it.

I have a Series of locations in standart lat, lon float degrees format, and need to calculate `buffer` around them in meters.

The locations  are from  Portugal, so I picked up the "right" `crs` here: https://epsg.io/3763,  which is `epsg:3763`

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['latitude'], df['longitude']),
                                 crs={'init' :'epsg:3763'})

gdf['radius'] = gdf.geometry.buffer(50)
```

According to the answer above, that should give me polygons around specified radius in meters, but that actually returns radius in the degrees.

I know, that should  be simple, but  I am still deeply confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Points in the dataframe are lat/lon. You need to initialize the dataframe with the lat/lon crs, then reproject.

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['latitude'], df['longitude']),
                                     crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'})
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3763)
gdf['radius'] = gdf.geometry.buffer(50)
```